# Documentation about Simple.Data.Mocking xml structure?

Tags: c#, simple.data

Anyone have links with the xml structure used for Simple.Data.Mocking?

Thanks!

Comment: Er, at the risk of sounding stupid, you don't mean [this](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/) do you? Do you mean the schema that the data is stored or something else?

Comment: I was talking about the xml format used in this example http://www.marcusoft.net/2011/10/simpledatathe-testing-story.html but perhaps I should use the InMemoryAdapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XmlMockAdapter is deprecated, so there won't be any documentation appearing for it beyond what is in the project's Unit Tests.

As you say, you should use InMemoryAdapter. :)

Comment: The docs for using the InMemoryAdapter can be found here, under "Testing Your Code": http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/index.html